# How to create a generalized function in Python to compare consecutive columns in pandas df for more that 100 columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have two data frames DF1 and DF2 with more that 280+ columns in both df, I have to compare both df on some unique key , so I am merging both df first ,

```
Compare  = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',on='unique_key',suffix=('_X','_Y'))
```

now , I want to compare consecutive columns like

```
Compare['compare_1'] =  Compare[_X]==Compare[_Y].
```

But, since columns are more than 280+ so I cant create compare columns for each set individually, I am looking for a function which can compare these consecutive columns.

I tried something like this,

```
col=df.columns
for x,i in enumerate(col):
    for y,j in enumerate(col):
        if  y-x==1 and i!=j:
            bina = df[i]-df[j]
            df['MOM_' + str(j) + '_' + str(i)] = bina
```

But , it is not working as my df are huge more that 100k records and loops are making it complex.

Comment: Can you add small data sample with 3 columns, 3 rows for both DataFrames and expected ouput?

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df1 = Compare.like('_X')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace('_X$','')
df2 = Compare.like('_Y')
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('_Y$','')

out = Compare.join(df1.sub(df2).add_prefix('MOM_'))
```